# right join on my linq query

Tags: linq, right-join

I want to return ALL items from db.Accounts.
How do I do a right join on the below linq query?

```
        var query = (
                     from tradeTbl in db.Trades
                     join acctTbl in db.Accounts on tradeTbl.AccountID equals acctTbl.AccountID
```

I've tried changing to

```
        var query = (
                    from acctTbl in db.Accounts
                    join tradeTbl in db.Trades on acctTbl.AccountID equals tradeTbl.AccountID
                    where acctTbl.AccountActive == true
```

still not working... if I put that same query in SSMS and change it to LEFT JOIN it works in SSMS

Comment: thats the issue... I do not know how to do it.  normally I would right RIGHT JOIN acctTbl

Comment: can't seem to get it right, I am posting code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it in terms of a left (outer) join by reversing the joined tables.

```
var query =
    from a in db.Accounts
    join t in db.Trades on a.AccountID equals t.AccountID into ts
    from t in ts.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select ...;
```

Comment: I must be missing something simple.  I've tried yours and it still does not return all values in db.Accounts.  If I put that same thing in SSMS and change it to LEFT JOIN, it works.

Comment: Sorry I'm going all over the place. It _should_ have been a left outer join, but I was mixing it up with an inner join.